# Why cannot i create a new db cluster using rds connector mule 4 for aurora

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, mule4

While i was trying to create a dbinstance using rds connector's ***createdbinstance*** with *aurora* mysql 5.6, It gives me this below error

```
The source cluster could not be found or cannot be accessed: cluster-name (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: DBClusterNotFoundFault; Request ID: c1bbcbb3-da7c-4e17-9440-3dfa260f1609)
```

and do i need to create it using aws cli.

Comment: how are you creating the cluster?

Comment: i tried to create a aurora db instance, but if i left the cluster name blank, it gives me allocated storage cannot be null. So i tried to give a new cluster name(not created). So it give me the above error. After that i tried to create a cluster for aurora using aws-cli and tried the new cluster name in rds createdbinstance connector it throws some error other errors

Comment: Aravind, are you running the commands on CLI

Comment: Yeah only for creating cluster i tried using cli. But my requirement is to try using mule 4 rds connector.

Comment: lot of values to fill. i will post a reference, not sure thats the same document that you are reading

Answer (score 0):

```
aws rds create-db-cluster \
    --db-cluster-identifier sample-cluster \
    --engine aurora-mysql \
    --engine-version 5.7.12 \
    --master-username master \
    --master-user-password secret99 \
    --db-subnet-group-name default \
    --vpc-security-group-ids sg-0b9130572daf3dc16
```

reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-cluster.html

Comment: Thanks arun, I have already excuted this successfully, but the error only comes when using mule 4 rds connector.

Comment: And there is no operation such as createDbCluster in rds mule4. there are only createDbInstance in it. Any references with mule 4 and aurora will be helpful